# Pictures uploaded sideway when upload through the phone - vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I made website with vue.js and upload photos options with file input.
All the time when I upload photo through the phone camera they are uploaded sideway - funny thing, if I upload the picture when the phone is horizontal so the picture uploaded as it should.
If I upload the picture from the computer it is ok - the problem is just on the phone.

I dont know what should I do to avoid this weird behavior.
Thank you guys :)

Comment: Without [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) it's difficult to give an answer, but likely your issue is due to the orientation information of the image stored in it's EXIF data.

Comment: Which more details? I am using chrome, mac.

This is the website,
https://adirimageboard.herokuapp.com

username: Adir
password: Welcome

Comment: Code around the issue (e.g., file upload methods), devices affected (all phones, just iphones, just android, etc.), original source of the images (such as, does the issue only happen with images from the phone's camera, or also on images downloaded from the internet then uploaded from the phone?) would all be good details.

Also your site requires a login

Comment: So the pictures that uploaded from any phone.
Iphone or android and just pictures that I took with the phone.
if it is downloaded picture it is ok.
And I put the username and password in the comment above.

Comment: You can also try to detect this from the screen orientation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation